# virtual field based on sql function

Tags: cakephp-4.x

i am trying to transfer my cake2.3 app to cake 4.x. Now it comes to virtual fields. In cake2.3 in my model i had a virtual fields description like:

```
function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
     parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
     $this->virtualFields['airtime'] = sprintf('ftoflighttime(%s.takeoff, %s.landing, %s.landingnd)', $this->alias, $this->alias, $this->alias);
}
```

ftoflighttime() is a custom mysql function.

my approach after reading the manual was like this. In my entity flights i appended some code like this.

```
    protected function _airborne()
    {
        $field = sprintf("%s",$this->func(ftoflighttime($this->takeoff,$this->landing,$this->landingnd)));
        return $field;
    }
```

...which obviously doesn't do the job.

Any help?

many thx

cdjw

Comment: Virtual fields used to be implemented as MySQL things, they are now pure PHP in the entity class. In other words, they run after the data has already been returned from the database, not as part of the query. Your main options would be to update your query to include the custom function call there as part of the `select`, or to re-implement the calculation in a PHP function instead. Which of those makes most sense will depend on your usage requirements, e.g. if you need to use this as part of a `where` clause, it'll need to be a change to your query.

Comment: Very nice!! Thanks. After a lot of reading I implemented this in cake which was much easier than I thought. But anyways you gave me an approval and now I am much more conscious that i am on the right track and understood the approach. Thx again